# Is there a way in Google Sheets to find specifc strings in a Form Responses range and organize them in colums?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet tab with form responses looking like this:
[image]

I would like to achieve, if possible using formulas located in the header row only, to extract some specific data located somewhere in the respones range (characters in black) and in the way it is depicted in the cells with characters in red.
Basically, in the heather row of the cells in red there are strings that can be found within the responses range in black and below each of them, and row by row, results show strings located either one column or two columns on the right of the found strings.
Formulas should be located in N1,O1 AND P1.
Here's the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x0Q6SigVE3x8xh1Uy7PKYM8DcFPWVcdVy_Hx3CsEXLY/edit?usp=sharing) of the spreadsheet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(D2:L,lambda(Σ,let(Δ,index(Σ,,1),if(offset(Δ,,-3)="",,
              ifna({torow(offset(Δ,,-2,,2),1),
                    torow(offset(index(Σ,xmatch(S1,Σ)),,1,,2),1),
                    torow(offset(index(Σ,xmatch(T1,Σ)),,1,,2),1)})))))
```

[image]

Comment: I am just amazed of the elegance of this solution! Thank you so much. Now it's going to be at least a week until I won't understand the sintax. Thanks.